# Match non-repetitive words from set with separator

Tags: regex, xsd

I'm trying to write a regex for matching a set of words separated by vertical lines, these words should occur only once in string. E.g.

```
mode1|mode2|mode3
```

But it should not match with:

```
mode1|mode2|mode2
mode1|
mode1|mode1
mode1|any_other_word
```

So far, I've written

```
^(?:(mode1|mode2|mode3)\|?)*(?!(?:mode1|mode2|mode3)\1)$
```

I believe it's close enough to desired result. But I can't make regex not matching for words occurred before, like:

```
mode1|mode2|mode3|mode2
```

Comment: You should mention the language or tool you're going to use to implement the regex as different regex flavours have different capacities

Comment: You want to match string including `|` ? Remember it's a special character in Regex!

Comment: @TareqMahmood so what? regex can match `?` in text for example : you just have to escape them so they are not misunderstood as a regex qualifier or operand

Comment: @Aaron, Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working on XSD, you should use an enumeration rather than a regex pattern to describe the expected value:

> ```
> <xs:simpleType name="modeString">
>   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
>     <xs:enumeration value="mode1"/>
>     <xs:enumeration value="mode2"/>
>     <xs:enumeration value="mode3"/>
>   </xs:restriction>
> </xs:simpleType>
> ```
>
> Adapted from
>   [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_facets.asp)

(Edited to remove my subpar regex answer and focus on the use of xsd enums).

Comment: @vmeln no indeed, it would require reworking your data structure, using an element containing 0-x "modeString" rather than your described string

Comment: Thanks, I will replace an attribute with sub-elements.